# Clarification on avoid_null_checks_in_equality_operators linter rule

Tags: dart

There is a linter rule which verifies that one don't check for null equality in the overridden `==` operator.
The rule is [here](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/avoid_null_checks_in_equality_operators.html).

I understand this rule but can't see how it is realized technically.
It seems that Dart itself makes some implicit check on `other != null` and `==` returns false in this case. Is this correct?

In other languages, e.g. Java, one needs to explicitly add this check in the overridden `equals`.

Second question is why then it does not check automatically on the type of `other` as well. Why it is ok to spare me as a programmer from checking on null, but I still need to check if `other is Person`? Are there cases when one overrides `==` and checks there for some other type then the type of that class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linter rule implementation is simple, it just checks whether you compare the argument of `operator ==` to `null`.
The reason you don't need to is that `e1 == e2` in Dart is defined to first evaluate `e1` and `e2` to a value, then give a result early if one or both of the values is `null`, and only otherwise it calls the `operator==` method on the value of `e1`.
So, when that method is called, you know for certain that the argument is not `null`.

The reason the `==` operator doesn't do more checks before calling the `operator==` method is that there are examples where that would be wrong.
In particular, `int` and `double` can be equal to each other. Having instances of different classes potentially being equal to each other is more common that you'd think (proxies, mocks, wrappers, Cartesian point vs polar point, `int` vs `double`).

The other check you could potentially do early is to say that an object is equal to *itself*, so `if (identical(this, other)) return true;`, but there is one counter-example forced upon the language: NaN, aka. `double.nan`. That particular "value" is not equal to itself (which breaks the reflexivity requirement for `==`, but is specified that way by the IEEE-754 standard which is what the CPUs implement natively).
If not for NaN, the language would probably have checked for identity before calling `operator==` too.

Answer (score 1):

> It seems that Dart itself makes some implicit check on `other != null` and `==` returns false in this case. Is this correct?

Yes.

> Second question is why then it does not check automatically on the type of `other` as well. Why it is ok to spare me as a programmer from checking on null, but I still need to check if `other is Person`? Are there cases when one overrides `==` and checks there for some other type then the type of that class?

It's less common, but there can be cases where you might want to allow a different type on the right-hand-side of the equality.  For example, the left-hand-side and right-hand-side might be easily convertible to each other or to a common type.  Imagine that you created, say, a `Complex` number class and that you wanted `Complex(real: 4.0, imaginary: 0.0) == 4` to be true.

Comment: Great example with complex number. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From the doc:

> no class can be equivalent to [null]

Meaning, when `other is Person` is true, then `other != null` is also true. This is because:

> The null object is the sole instance of the built-in class `Null`.

(https://dart.dev/guides/language/spec)

So every instance check against any type but `Null` will return `false` for `null`:

```dart
class A {}

void main() {
  final x = null;
  final a = A();
  print(x is Null); // true
  print(x is A);    // false
  print(a is Null); // false
  print(a is A);    // true
}
```